# Restoring eclipse's initial Android welcome screen

Tags: android, eclipse

After the first installation of the Eclipse/Android SDK/ADT package. When you run it for the 1st time, you get a welcome screen that offers a very basic set of tutorials. I forget exactly where they are, but I think it works you through some kind of a "Hello World" type program. I'm trying to introduce some friends of mine (programers with no Android exposure) to android programing and would like to know how I can re-set Eclipse to show that screen again.
- Any comments welcome.

Comment: Thank you "twlkyao", for re-writing the question and fixing the grammar and spelling problems. It appears your English is better then mine, and I grew up in the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed ADT bundle from android website, u'll have it in

Eclipse --> Help --> Android IDE

Comment: I installed ADT from "Add Software" in Eclipse and I don't have Android IDE in Help... is this how it suposed to be? Also if I go to welcome screen I have no Android specific tutorials?

Comment: @jj_, Well i've never installed ADT from eclipse, but i guess u won't have Android IDE option in Help.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Help --> Welcome in Eclipse.